# Is there a Cisco IOS command for finding out the serial number of a switch / router?

Tags: cisco, router, switch, ios

I am doing an inventory of all of our switches and I was wondering if there's a Cisco IOS command that will return the serial number for a switch and router?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `show version` should do it for you. You can also try `show inventory` but that command isn't universally supported.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, that info's usually in the output of [`show version`](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/switches/catalyst-6500-series-switches/41361-serial-41361.html) , though that might vary with specific devices and software versions.

Answer (score 1):

Some Cisco products (ranging from their SMB line to big-boy ASRs) use "show inventory" for displaying pertinent module and Serial Number information.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to install observium server and via SNMP you can monitor and archive all information in real time.